# Why are some accounts with even huge number of badges suspended?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

By chance I happened to look at the profile (link of profile deleted) which is suspended for "rule violations". It was bit strange that a person with so many badges (gold, silver etc) with so many answers with good number of votes has been suspended. I find it hard to believe that a person with so many up-votes really violates the rules and gets suspended. In my view such a person is probably passionate enough to spend time and earn so many badges. Are such cases of suspension usual or truly exceptional? Doesn't suspension of such accounts send a wrong signal to the people who are new here? Perhaps the reasons for suspension should be more objective (like no of posts flagged etc) and mentioned in the profile.

Comment: Sorry, I had first included the link to the account profile, but I figured out it would be like targeting a specific user so I deleted the profile link.

Comment: The answer is that sometimes people with many badges and high reputation misbehave too. When they misbehave badly enough, they get suspended, like people with fewer badges and lower reputation.

Comment: Why so many downvotes...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. There is a reason why moderators here are humans (I have only met one other moderator, but the assumption seems to be sensible) and not machines. Do you want to be suspended because another user wants to and simply flags your posts for no reason?
2. Suspended users are free to state publicly why they were suspended after their suspension ends. It is not always in the interest of the suspended user to do so, and we have no public trials here.
3. It certainly happens from time to time that high ranking users get suspended. The rules apply to everyone. Why should it be any different?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I feel sad that even high achievers sometimes behavior in poor manner. Let's hope the suspension policies really help them to change their behavior and the community here benefits as a whole from their knowledge.